# Sentiment towards a keyword

Tags: sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

I have been looking around for Sentiment and text analysis services but most of them seem to analyse the whole text and provide one result for it.

Is there a way of analysing the same piece of text against two different keywords? For example, the same article could be talking about two entities, positively towards one and negatively towards the other.

How could one get these two sentiments within the same text? Is there a service or API already for that?

I have found IBM's AlchemyAPI but doesn't seem to return accurate results...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is aspect-based sentiment analysis. There are lots of algorithms with different precisions and recalls for this aspect-based sentiment analysis.

You can use [Aylien](http://aylien.com)'s text analysis api.